# Битовые операции. Разбор xml файла С++

Tags: c++

Подскажите, есть файл вида:
test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<authorization>
    <user name="user1"  login="login1" password="password1">
        <role type="rerrer"/>
        <role type="engineer"/> 
    </user>
    <user name="user2"  login="login2" password="password2" role="operator" />
    <user name="user3"  login="login3" password="password3" role="engineer" />
    <user name="user4"  login="login4" password="password4" role="installer" />
</authorization>
```

Делаю разбор этого файла с помощью библиотеки tinyxml2.
Создаю структуру.

CAuthorizationData.h

```
#ifndef CAUTHORIZATIONDATA_H
#define CAUTHORIZATIONDATA_H
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace Authorization
{

 struct CAuthorizationData 
 {
    struct CUserData
    {
        std::string _name;
        std::string _login;
        std::string _password;

        enum class RolesType
        {
            _none,
            _viewer,
            _operator,
            _engineer,
            _installer
        };

        std::vector<RolesType> _roles;
    };

    std::vector<CUserData> _users;
 };

}

#endif // CSETTINGSDATA_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include "CAuthorization.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace tinyxml2;
using namespace Authorization;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    CAuthorization userInfo;    
    if (userInfo.Load ("impr1_auth.xml"))
    {
    for (const auto &User: userInfo.Data()._users)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << User._name << endl;
        cout << "Login: " << User._login << endl;
        cout << "Password: " << User._password << endl << endl;     
    }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, как вывести роли на экран, если есть такое условие

```
 // - бит 0=1 - viewer
        // - бит 1=1 - operator
        // - бит 2=1 - engineer
        // - бит 3=1 - installer



#define VIEWER 0x01
#define OPERATOR 0x02
#define ENGINEER 0x04
#define INSTALLER 0x08
```

Comment: а какой бит не сказано?

Comment: Вопрос не правильно сформулирован. Битовые операции не имеют никакого отношения к XML. Кроме того, не ясно в каком виде будут выводится роли, и что выводит если идет обладание двумя ролями. Потрудитесь написать вопрос правильно пожайлуста.

Comment: Почитайте битовые операции, особенно AND. Например тут http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/bitovye-operatory

Comment: `if (role & VIEWER) cout << "роль вью"; ` как-то так. Роль достать с юзера.